# TypeError: "float" object is not iterable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, csv, punctuation

The first thing is that I import a .csv file and I´m working some tasks without any problem, but now I have this issue that I´m not able to solve.
After defining a function I expected to remove all punctuations from the dataset. But I received a series of errors that I didn´t expect, I was following the same steps of an online course but this happen and I follow behind.

```
# import the data using read_csv
data = pd.read_csv("text_data.csv")
data

# Let's define a function to remove punctuations

def punc(message):
    no_punc = [char for char in message if char not in string.punctuation]
    join_punc = "".join(no_punc)

    return join_punc

# Let's remove punctuations from our dataset 
data["new_verified_reviews"] = data["verified_reviews"].apply(punc)
```

```
**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)**
Cell In[62], line 2
      1 # Let's remove punctuations from our dataset 
----> 2 data["new_verified_reviews"] = data["verified_reviews"].apply(punc)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4753, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, by_row, **kwargs)
   4625 def apply(
   4626     self,
   4627     func: AggFuncType,
   (...)
   4632     **kwargs,
   4633 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   4634     """
   4635     Invoke function on values of Series.
   4636 
   (...)
   4751     dtype: float64
   4752     """
-> 4753     return SeriesApply(
   4754         self,
   4755         func,
   4756         convert_dtype=convert_dtype,
   4757         by_row=by_row,
   4758         args=args,
   4759         kwargs=kwargs,
   4760     ).apply()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1207, in SeriesApply.apply(self)
   1204     return self.apply_compat()
   1206 # self.func is Callable
-> 1207 return self.apply_standard()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1287, in SeriesApply.apply_standard(self)
   1281 # row-wise access
   1282 # apply doesn't have a `na_action` keyword and for backward compat reasons
   1283 # we need to give `na_action="ignore"` for categorical data.
   1284 # TODO: remove the `na_action="ignore"` when that default has been changed in
   1285 #  Categorical (GH51645).
   1286 action = "ignore" if isinstance(obj.dtype, CategoricalDtype) else None
-> 1287 mapped = obj._map_values(
   1288     mapper=curried, na_action=action, convert=self.convert_dtype
   1289 )
   1291 if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], ABCSeries):
   1292     # GH#43986 Need to do list(mapped) in order to get treated as nested
   1293     #  See also GH#25959 regarding EA support
   1294     return obj._constructor_expanddim(list(mapped), index=obj.index)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py:921, in IndexOpsMixin._map_values(self, mapper, na_action, convert)
    918 if isinstance(arr, ExtensionArray):
    919     return arr.map(mapper, na_action=na_action)
--> 921 return algorithms.map_array(arr, mapper, na_action=na_action, convert=convert)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py:1814, in map_array(arr, mapper, na_action, convert)
   1812 values = arr.astype(object, copy=False)
   1813 if na_action is None:
-> 1814     return lib.map_infer(values, mapper, convert=convert)
   1815 else:
   1816     return lib.map_infer_mask(
   1817         values, mapper, mask=isna(values).view(np.uint8), convert=convert
   1818     )

File lib.pyx:2917, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

Cell In[59], line 5, in punc(words)
      4 def punc(words):
----> 5     no_punc = [char for char in words if char not in string.punctuation]
      6     join_punc = "".join(no_punc)
      8     return join_punc

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: "verified_reviews" column contains floats. Check with the following code : `data["verified_reviews"].apply(type).value_counts()`

Comment: @PandaKim I get the following: 
verified_reviews
<class 'str'>      3149
<class 'float'>       1
Name: count, dtype: int64

Comment: yeah. there is float. so cant use your code.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Solving this problem is not difficult at all. However, you need to decide how to handle the floats in the column to solve it. Extract the floats from the column and check them.

Comment: Most likely NaNs, you can probably use `if pd.isna(words): return ''` to ignore them. Or `if isinstance(words, str): [rest of your code]`

Comment: Just check what those floats are as @PandasKim suggested to be sure that it's OK to drop them ;)

Comment: You could also clean up your data with `fillna` e.g. `data["new_verified_reviews"] = data["verified_reviews"].fillna('').apply(punc)`